# Room - Android. How to request data from multiple entities?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have 4 different entities with the same type of data..

```
class {
   val Int
   val String
   val String
}
```

I am using ViewModel to request the data and right now I have for Observables which updates the list adapter.

```
  tagsViewModel.getAllText().observe(this,
            Observer<List<Text>> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
```

My problem is that I am having some troubles when updating the ui so I wanted to just do one request to get the 4 different types of entities but I don't know how to get one only list with all different classes.

This is a class type

```
@Entity(tableName = "text")
data class Text(override var content: String, override var date: Long, override var type: String = AppConstants.TYPE_TEXT) : BaseTag() {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    override var id: Int = 0
}
```

and Base interface

```
abstract class BaseTag {
    abstract val content: String?
    abstract val date: Long?
    abstract val id: Int?
    abstract val type: String?
}
```

I would like to do this request:

```
{ texts : [Text,Text,Text],
  emails : [Email,Email,Email]...
}
```

So... Is there any simple way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ```
tagsViewModel.getAllText().observe(this,
            Observer<List< BaseTag >> { t -> adapter.setTags(t!!) })
```

Try this!

Comment: I did your way and I can't use an abstract class with room. error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<com.easynfc.data.model.BaseTag>> getList();
                                                                                                ^

Comment: Yeah! You may need to Transform the LiveData to hold the Inteface instead of concrete implementation.

Comment: Thats what I did and was not able to do it. at least Room does not work with abstract classes

Comment: Not talking about room. Room returns `LiveData<List<Text>>` but your viewmodel should transform it to `LiveData<List< BaseTag >>` via `Transformations` or a `MediatorLiveData`

Comment: Ok I didn't know what you meant I take a look. many Thanks.